# How to manage android back button activity in xamarin.forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, back-button

forms app I have four screens namely main screen , screen 2 ,list screen and settings screen so main screen is the entry screen and screen 2 is the one where all the operations are performed here and from here I can navigate to list screen and settings screen ,there is a close button in this screen 2 on click of it ,it pops back to main screen .so when I click on back button in android from main screen it takes me back to screen 2 instead of **exiting from the app** and on the click of back button again it takes me to list screen ,so can anyone please guide me how to tackle this back button activity ?

Comment: Hi, can you show your codes? By screen, do you mean page? That means you have four pages in your Activity, is it right? And the close button is your ui control, not the back key?

Comment: Hi yeah I meant four pages and close button is UI control